# Vue3 migration "Could not resolve dependency: peer vue@"^2.x" from @vue/vue2-jest@29.2.2" Error

Tags: vuejs3

While resolving: vma@0.6.9
Found: vue@3.2.47
node_modules/vue
dev vue@"^3.2.47" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer vue@"^2.x" from @vue/vue2-jest@29.2.2
node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest
dev @vue/vue2-jest@"^29.2.2" from the root project

trying to run my project after I updated my vue2 version to version3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Remove the `vue2-jest` item from your `package.json`, remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating a compatibility issue between the installed version of the vue package (vue@3.2.47) and the required version specified by the @vue/vue2-jest package (peer vue@"^2.x").

In order to resolve this issue, you need to either upgrade the @vue/vue2-jest package to a version that is compatible with vue@3.2.47, or downgrade the installed version of the vue package to a version that satisfies the requirements of @vue/vue2-jest.